# combination type="submit" and onclick in 1 button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I want to redirect to another link after generate pdf file
how to solve the both problem
I use this code just generate file

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="homepage(); return false;">Generate</button>
```

when try this code (`<input type="submit" onclick="homepage(); return false;" value="Calculate"/>`) just redirect to my homepage

Comment: Show us your `homepage` function code.

Comment: Just class the function `homepage()` after the PDF generate function. Why do you need to call it in the `onclick` event?

Comment: considering your `button` is inside an `<form>`, you can include the `homepage()` inside `<form onSubmit = "homepage()">` if you want `homepage()` to run before page submit.

Comment: I write on codeigniter
the code I want submit to controller and than create pdf file, in the same time I want to redirect baseurl, not to remain in form

Comment: You cannot do two actions at the same time. Javascript is single threaded, synchronous. You could do an AJAX request with a low timeout value, but you still have to ensure that the server receives the request. A typical response time is <200ms, if your function takes a while you could set the timeout to 1000 and then redirect the user.

Comment: you are creating the pdf file in controller right, if so you can call [redirect()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) after pdf is created